# An issue with vertical parent scrollview and two children recycler-view in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview, nestedrecyclerview

I've the following use case -

```
<ScrollView> // parent
   <ContentView/> // content
</ScrollView>
```

I do not have any access to the parent ScrollView because the library only allows setting the content view. And it doesn't provide any API or reference to modify the attributes of the parent ScrollView. And the content of ContentView is arbitrary in a way that it can take recycler-view, list-view and any other views with scrolling effects.

Because I do not have access to the parent ScrollView, I can't change its property / attributes anyhow. This causes the issue will ill-behaved scrolling. This specially shows the problem when

```
<ScrollView>
 <ContentView>
    <LinearLayout orientation=horizonal>
      <RecyclerView/>
      <RecyclerView/>
    </LinearLayout>
 <ContentView>
<ScrollView
```

And this causes two recycler-views to scroll together, while I want individual recycler-view scroll independently.

I was thinking of a solution that I can build a container-view and the children of container-view are agnostic of its ScrollView parent.  So that my recycler-views have no knowledge of its parent ScrollView.

Is there any way to implement such solution? Have you ever encountered such an issue and how did you fix it?

Comment: Did you try adding android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" on your RecyclerViews?

Comment: I did try to use NestedScrollView and I did try with the android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" as well. It did not have any impact on the scrolling.